# Should argc and argv be used if no arguments are needed?

Tags: c++

Is there any disadvantage to using argc and argv when no arguments are needed for a program? Would the program have worse performance than without these being defined, or are argc and argv already *implicitly defined*? Essentially, I understand these don't have to be included in a main function if arguments aren't necessary, but is there any disadvantage to including them and not using them?

Comment: None whatsoever

Comment: How would you use them anyway? (Note that generally speaking it's bad practice to repurpose parameters anyway).

Comment: Depending on the compiler and compilation flags, you will get a warning if you declare them but don't use them.  That's the only difference.

Comment: See also: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard (at least for c++17) appears to be neutral on this topic: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf. It just says C++ compilers "shall allow both" `int main()` and `int main(int, char**)`

So any answer you get will be an opinion :).

For my money, I would leave them out until you need them. Another author glancing at your method signature will know immediately that the method takes no parameters.

EDIT: To your performance question: a compiler is free to implement the specification in any way. I can't imagine a compiler having a performance penalty for the usage you specify (unused params). To be certain, you can disassemble the output of the compiler you are using. Or you could even compare them with diff, they might be identical byte-for-byte.